# Daily NAV and daily number of transactions of ETFs

Tags: etf, yahoofinance, historical

Does anyone know how can I get the historical, daily NAV of a specific ETF, for example SPD or IWM?
and how can I get the number of daily transaction of a specific ETF? Yahoo finance has daily opening, high, low, closing values, but no NAV.

Comment: For IWM you can get daily NAV since May 22, 2000 (the date of inception)  in a spreadsheet on the iShares web site https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239710/ishares-russell-2000-etf (see green download icon at top right)

Comment: SPD is put out by a company called Simplify Asset Management that I don't know, but they can probbly give you NAVs also.

Comment: Number of transactions is a rather unusual metric. What would the number of trades tell you. With the proliferation of sweeping orders and matching engines, large orders are split and small ones are consolidated all the time. You can run COUNT on the consolidated trade log but I doubt the utility. It may have some use if you extract outliers during particular liquidity events such as auctions.

Comment: @SergeiRodionov the number of transactions has a high correlation with the volume. I wanna compare two different datasets, one includes the volume and the other includes the number of transactions.

Comment: @noob2 Tnx, but that spreadsheet is corrupted.

Comment: @RSalimi Trade volume and trade count will be highly correlated, for sure. I ran a quick query correlating trades and volumes on 500+ iShares/MSCI ETFs traded on the US exchanges and the correlation was 94% on Dec-26, 2021. For stocks in general it is around 85% - all expected. My point was that the aggregate count was too close to volume. I would be more interested in the distribution, and percentiles, and outliers in the trade counts as a source of insights.